# How to show and hide toggle button when screen resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to show my userlist (by default and no toggle) when the screen is in full size and provide a toggle when the screen is in mobile size which could help show/hide the list.

I am using the following the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Users Online</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <div ng-repeat="user in chatCtrl.userList">{{user}}</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#demo").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
    $(".btn").html(' Users Online');
  });
  $("#demo").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
    $(".btn").html(' Users Online');
  });
});
</script>
```

It gives me the toggle even when the screen in full size.

So just one question: how to only show the toggle button when screen collapses?

Any suggestion and reference will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your button an id and use a media query

```
    @media(min-width:768px){
      #id-for-button{
        display:none;
      }
    }
```

It will be hidden on everything above 768px or the screen size that you choose.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Should it be "768px". Anyway, it helps and works well. Thanks a lot.@1Bladesforhire